# how to loop an input function until score is found

Tags: python, loops, input

I am learning python and I am at 'interacting functions'. This is the 'find the ball game' where **I want to loop the input until the correct glass is chosen in *'check_guess' function***

***to shuffle the list***

```
def shuffle_list(mylist):
    shuffle(mylist)
    return mylist
```

***3 glasses and one has the ball***

```
mylist = ['','O','']
```

***interacting the functions***

```
def check_guess(mylist, guess):
    
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print('Correct')
                
    else:
        print('Wrong Guess')
        print(mylist)
```

#INITIAL LIST

```
mylist = ['','O','']
```

#SHUFFLE LIST

```
mixedup_list = shuffle_list(mylist)
```

#USER GUESS

```
guess = player_guess()
```

#CHECK GUESS

```
check_guess(mixedup_list,guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a while loop. You can use `break` to break out of the loop whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `check_guess` function so it returns True when the guess is correct and then build a while loop around the `player_guess` function.

```py
def check_guess(mylist, guess):
    
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print('Correct')
        return True
                
    else:
        print('Wrong Guess')
        print(mylist)
        return False

check = False
while check == False:
    guess = player_guess()
    check = check_guess(mixedup_list, guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a `while True` loop, and `break` out of the loop when the correct answer is chosen.

```
while True:
    # shuffle the balls
    # ask for a guess
    if guess is correct:
        print('Correct!')
        break
    else:
        print('Too bad, try again')
        # loop will repeat
```

Comment: with a wrong answer, its looping the 'too bad, try again'

Comment: @buri I don't understand your comment.  Isn't that exactly what it should do?  Are you saying that if the answer is wrong, it _shouldn't_ print a message?